# First slide in bxslider to start in the middle of container not left

Tags: jquery, css, bxslider

When I give my bxslider container a width of 100% the first slide always appears on the left and the next slide is cropped. What I want is for the first slide to show in the center and the prev and next slides be cropped on both sides. Is this possible?

HTML:

```
<div id="container-carousel">
    <ul class="carousel">
        <li><img src="http://parade.condenast.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/pizza-cat.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://parade.condenast.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/pizza-cat.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://parade.condenast.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/pizza-cat.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://parade.condenast.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/pizza-cat.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container-carousel {
    width: 750px;
    border: 3px solid red;
}

.bx-wrapper {
   min-width: 100%;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('.carousel').bxSlider({
    slideWidth: 500,
    minSlides: 1,
    moveSlides: 1,
    slideMargin: 0
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uHCZ8/

**SOLVED (Responsive):** http://jsfiddle.net/TPspv/4/

Comment: code pleaseeeeee, fiddle for better answer

Comment: Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/uHCZ8/
As you can see the first slide starts on the left.

Comment: This may help you out: http://htmldoc.net/2012/11/centered-bxslider-slideshow-with-custom-slide-opacity/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please refer to this [JS Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/devangkantharia/TPspv/3/)

> JS Code

```
$(function() {
    $('.carousel').bxSlider({
        pager: false,
        slideWidth: 200,
        minSlides: 1,
        maxSlides: 1,
        moveSlides: 1,
        adaptiveHeight: true,
        slideMargin: 10
    });

    $('.bx-wrapper').first().css('max-width', '240px');
});
```

> Css Code:

```
.carouselWrapper {
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 240px;
}


.carouselWrapper .bx-viewport {
    padding-left: 20px;
    width: inherit !important
}

.carousel .slide .imgslide {    overflow: hidden; }
.carousel .slide .imgslide img { width: 100%; }
```

If you have further query, then please comment below.

Regards D.

Comment: Thanks Devang, your solution helped me solve my issue. The only thing is that your solution was no responsive, but I was able to fix that: http://jsfiddle.net/TPspv/4/

Comment: Yes, for responsive, you need to have some changes in js as well as css. If you have any other queries, then let me know. By the way, you didn't mention about responsive in your question initially. Regards D.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this is what you want, but let me know if it is not.  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uHCZ8/1/)

You needed to do two things to achieve this.  Firstly, you had to take out the width of the slide.

### jQuery

```
$('.carousel').bxSlider({
    minSlides: 1,
    moveSlides: 1,
    slideMargin: 0
});
```

Then you need to add `margin: 0 auto` to each image to center it in the li.

### CSS

```
.carousel li img {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Let me know if this is what you wanted.

Comment: Actually in the question it is mentioned, that "What I want is for the first slide to show in the center and the prev and next slides be cropped on both sides. Is this possible?" This means, previous and next slides are to be copped, showing some portion of the slides.